# How should Android back button behave when it's not possible to go back to previous screen?

Tags: navigation, android, back-button, onboarding

I'm designing an on-boarding process and it is not always possible to go to the previous screen with the Android back button. So in this case I have two options:

1. Let user know that is not possible to go to previous screen.
2. Minimise the app (Go to the Android home screen)

Which one would you prefer (and why) or can you provide another solution? Existing examples would be appreciated.

Comment: This question sounds pretty opinion-based, which isn't what this website is for. Could you formulate the question in such a way that there is an absolute answer to it?

Comment: HI @MJB, I reformulated question:) These are just two solutions that I came with, of course I would appreciate other solutions. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: minimize the app and go to android home screen

Comment: @uttham thanks! That feels like the most native solution.

Comment: Is there a way in settings to control whether or not the back button can close the app? I want to keep tapping until i reach the original screen then not close when i continue to keep tapping back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default an Android application minimizes and returns to the home screen when it is no longer possible to go back further inside the app itself. Deviating from such a pattern is likely to result in irritation and annoyance amongst users.

Or as the say in the [android guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)

> Consistent navigation is an essential component of the overall user experience. Few things frustrate users more than basic navigation that behaves in inconsistent and unexpected ways. Thoughtfully following the guidelines for Back and Up will make your app's navigation predictable and reliable for your users.